# Real-time soft shadows - How do you implement in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, real-time, shadow, lighting

What is the state of the art for rendering real-time soft shadows (with physically accurate penumbra, rather than just blurred edges) in OpenGL?  Are there techniques for doing this completely on the GPU?  How much CPU is generally required?  Are there techniques out there for both point lights and area lights?

Point me towards any resources that you know about and/or give me a quick summary if you can.

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenGL specifically? The algorithm would work in any rasterizing API.

Comment: NVidia have a good paper on a technique known as Percentage Closer Soft Shadows: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/docs/shadow_PCSS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> (with physically accurate penumbra, rather than just blurred edges)

The interesting part about soft shadows is, that in reality it's just a blurring as well: The shadow silhouette gets convoluted with the lightsource's projected intensity distribution. Which is just the same as using the lightsources appearance as the convolution (read blurring) kernel.